# Rails: Why do we have to use current user to build message ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am new to Ruby on Rails and observed during a tutorial of Message Board that the new message was created as show below.

My point is, why do we have to build a message using current_user.build or current_user.new (I read that build is alias of new)

In Message model, we can just create a variable user_id and store in it the current_user.id and this way we know which message was created by which user.

What is the reason behind using current_user.build

```
def new
    @message = current_user.messages.build
end

def create
    @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
    if @message.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: Post the schema for your Message model. Is should have an attribute :user_id in it, which your build statement will automatically populate.

Comment: Yes there is user_id as an integer. So does Rail automatically follow convention that because User is the model so in Message, there has to be user_id ?

As in _id is as per convention ?

Comment: Exactly. If user_id is in the table then when you do current_user.messages.build, it'll automatically populate it.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
 @message = current_user.messages.build
```

looks like it would be the same, logically, as doing this:

```
@message = Message.new(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

and it almost is, with one important exception.  If you have already defined `current_user`, and called `.messages` on that object, rails will look up the associated messages and **cache them** for efficiency, so that if you do `current_user.messages` again in that same action you don't need to look them up again.  If you then do `@message = Message.create(:user_id => current_user.id)`, you've made the association in the database, but the current_user object in memory **doesn't know about the change**, and so if you do `current_user.messages` you might not get the new message.

On the other hand, doing `current_user.messages.build` updates the cached association in the process, so `current_user.messages` **will** include the new message.

Comment: But what about a situation where there is a Comment model, which is basically replies to Message model. As in people read a message and reply to it. In this case we build @comment = message.comments.build like this ?

Comment: Just one little addition: Calling `current_user.messages.build` will not trigger a database query to for the other messages. This will first take place when you actually use the messages (e.g. call an array-like method on it)

Comment: @Tahseen yes you could build a comment like that.

Comment: So if I build like @commernt = message.comments.build then in that I should have a variable message_id in comment table ? Which would be automatically filled by build ? Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes - you need to save it too.  `.build` sets up a new object but doesn't save it.

Comment: But then note that I want to associate the comment to user also. How can then I do that ? Manually comment.user_id = current_user.id ?

Comment: yep, eg `@comment = message.comments.build(:user => current_user)`

Answer (score 1):

There is one important difference between these two lines:

```
current_user.messages.build
```

and

```
Message.new(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

On the first line, you just don't have to know how the relation is build and how the keys are set up. What if one day you'd like to change it to a many-to-many relationship? Or if you'd like to add conditions (e.g. `deleted_at => nil`). 
The one place to set up your relations is inside of your models. And there should only be rare cases in which you'd have to reference details from this relations *outside* of your models.

Comment: I think that this is probably the primary reason it's preferred by convention, rather than my suggestions of "neatness" and "updates the cached proxy" (both of which are true but possibly secondary).

Answer (score 0):

While using `current_user.messages.build`, it automatically assign `user_id` for the object.But in case of `Message.new` you should have to pass `user_id` explicitly. e.g `Message.new(:user_id=>current_user.id)`.